# detect and perform action when user logs out of GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, logout

I need my (python) google app to perform an action (submit a form) if the user logs out.  This is simple enough to do if they use the logout links in my app, but if they log out from a gmail page or something, I don't know how to handle it.

Another possible source of error would be if the user closed the browser window, shut down their computer, etc. resulting in a log-off.  Is this scenario is equivalent to what I describe in the previous paragraph, or are they different somehow?

---

To expand this question since it seems the above is not at all trivial: if I set a cleanup function on a timeout, will the python session in fact continue to run in the GAE cloud after the cookie expires, and actually execute the timeout function?

Comment: Is there a reason that implementing some type of "dead session" cleanup after a specified timeout wouldn't work?

Comment: Yeah, that's my backup option.  I'm new to this kind of programming and wanted to know if this were possible.

Comment: Another question about this option asked in above edit.

Comment: The answer to your followup question is "no."  App Engine is stateless.

Comment: Thank you Kluin.  Seems that this is not an easy problem to take care of.

Answer (score 2):

Close browser window and shut down computer result log out because of session expired (cookie). It is slightly different from user click log out manually. 
In both case, I don't think GAE can track these behaviors.

The best thing that I can think about is to develop a browser extension. 
Or just don't design the service based on detecting user's log out.